# Excel Count If Function with additional range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a COUNTIF function with an additional range of values to match at the end. Why does it not work and how can I get it to work.

```
=COUNTIF('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877,AND('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877>=548,'[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877<=554)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use `COUNTIFS` you subtract one `COUNTIF` from another like this

`=COUNTIF('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877,">=548")-COUNTIF('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877,">554")`

that counts between 548 and 554 inclusive

Comment: nice trick! particularly useful for Excel version prior to 2007

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `COUNTIF` with `AND` because the second part must be a **criteria**.
Plus, the second part (criteria) shouldn't repeat the range.

You can use [`COUNTIFS`](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/20080127.htm) if you are using Excel version 2007 or higher. Else, you can use an array formula.

Something like this maybe:

```
=COUNTIFS('[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877,">=548",
          '[DATABASE 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AC$3:$AC$51877,"<=554")
```